# Didn't ask camera permission in android device using sencha touch 2.4 and cordova

Tags: android, cordova, camera, sencha-touch-2, cordova-plugins

I am totally confused while developing Android application using Sencha touch and Cordova. I am developing application which needs to access camera feature in Android device. I checked all check points.

Check Points:

- Sencha Touch Command Version - 5.0.1.231
- cordova version - 4.3.0
- Sencha Touch Version - 4.2.0
- Add latest cordova camera plugin

org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.4 "Camera"

- In config.xml file,
- In AndroidManifest.xml file,
- In app.json file,

> "builds": {
>           "web": {"default": true},
>           "native": {
>               "packager": "cordova",
>               "cordova" : {
>                   "config": {
>                       // Uncomment the line below and add the platforms you wish to build for
>                       "platforms": "android",
>                       "id": "com.abc.xyz",
>                       "name": "xyz"
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       },
>       ...
>       "js": [
>           {
>               "path": "cordova.js",
>               "remote": true
>           },

....

```
"resources": [
    "config.xml",
```

....

- In app.js

> requires: [
>                     'Ext.MessageBox',
>                     'Ext.device.Camera',
>                     'Ext.Ajax',
>                     'Ext.data.JsonP',
>                     'Ext.device.Device',
>                     'Ext.field.File',
>                     'Ext.field.FileInput',
>                     'Ext.device.Connection'
>                 ],

```
    Please help me to find out how to access camera permission in android using sencha touch and cordova.
```

Comment: did you added camera permission in config.xml?

Comment: Ya i added camera plugin but no change

Comment: did you tried adding camera plugin using cmd?

Comment: Yes i added camera plugin through CLI only

Answer (score 0):

Add permission to config.xml:

```
<feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
```

If the problem persists, make sure you do [all steps](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) correctly

Comment: ya i added all steps and checked camera plugin documents too. but its not working man. thanks for your reply.